# How to get the value without "index" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to get an average number of star (means result should get 1.5) ?
Note: The value to get is without index because it is not under ListView.builder
Below is the sample json code and this is how what i tried till now.

> JSON

```
{
    "message": "feedbacks for restaurant branch returened",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "comment": "Investor Operations Coordinator",
            "star": 1,
        }
        {
            "id": "4",
            "comment": "Investor Operations Coordinator",
            "star": 2,
        }
    ]
 }
```

> DART

```
  Widget buildReviewNumbers(List<FeedbacksData> data) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
          Text(
            data[index].star.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 30.0),
          ),
        
      ],
    );
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id)

```
final map = {
  "message": "feedbacks for restaurant branch returened",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "comment": "Investor Operations Coordinator",
      "star": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "comment": "Investor Operations Coordinator",
      "star": 2,
    }
  ]
};


void main() {
  
  final data = map['data'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
  
  var total = 0;
  
  data.forEach((e) {
    total += e['star'] as int;
  });
  
  print(total/ data.length);
}
```

For your case:

```
Widget buildReviewNumbers(List<FeedbacksData> data) {
    var total = 0;
  
    data.forEach((e) {
      total += e.star;
    });

    return Text(
      '${total/data.length}',
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize:30.0),
    );
}
```

Comment: It works in dart pad and i have updated my dart code, so kindly check it

Comment: you want to display both values or only the avarege (1.5)?

Comment: i want to display only an average (1.5)

Comment: so you don't need a column with all value, just do that, ill update my code

Comment: Actually inside Column Widget, there are lots of Text Widgets so i just shared a piece of Column Widget.

Comment: ooh a see, I didn't know that so I removed the column, try to adapt it, if you can't call me. Don't forget the thumb :) see you

Comment: There is an error on `data['data']` it shows "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'."

Comment: well true, can you show me this FeedbacksData object??

Comment: I've made a change to the code I gave you, I didn't saw that data was already the list. Now since I dont know whats inside this FeedbacksData object, i dont know if you access the star value with e['star'] or e.star

Comment: It's not working if i try `e.star` then i'm getting all the star numbers like 1 2 and so on. And if i try `e['star']` then i'm getting "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'FeedbacksData'."

Comment: I've updated the code. see it again call me if you can't do, also update the code for me to see what you've changed so far

Comment: it is displaying `1.5` then under 1.5  displaying `2`

Comment: because you're still using your for loop and rendering 1 Text widget for each entry in your list, you don't need it anymore if you just want to render the avarage

Comment: Yes i want to render the average, so how to prevent this for loop?

Comment: simply remove for  this (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)

Comment: i have already removed check this code `Widget buildReviewNumbers(List<FeedbacksData> data) {
    var total = 0;

    data.forEach((e) {
      total += e.star as int;
    });

    return Column(children: [
      Text(
        '${total / data.length}',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 30.0),
      ),
    ]);
  }`

Comment: in this case i dont know... you probably have another widget below rendering it

Comment: using higher order functions, you can go like: `double  average = data.map((m) => m['star']).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / data.length;`

Answer (score 0):

Your jsondata of type Map dynamic has to be converted to a list of Feedbacks according to your code. Once done just use the map operator to loop through your data.

```
Column(
    children: data.map((item) => Text(item.star.toString())).toList(); 
);
```

For lack of more info on what Feedbacks data looks like i shortened it to this.

Comment: That doesn’t work because it says "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'FeedbacksData'." Anyway i have my dart code

Comment: Can we see what feedbacks Data looks like?

Comment: You can see the Json data, that data itself FeedbacksData.

Comment: the json data when encoded returns a Map<String, dynamic> but you are passing a list of feedbackdata to your function. Anyways you can use the map operator on your list to populate your list. I will update my answer now

Comment: I'm getting all the `star` numbers but i want an average (1.5).

Comment: Then you do not need to loop over the text widget. You do not need a loop at all. I think @pedro pimont answer should get you there but instead of e['star'] it should be e.star

Comment: I want to display an average number of `star` not to get all number of `star`. I tried with `e.star` then i'm getting all numbers of `star`.

Comment: e.star / data.length should give you the average.

Comment: it is displaying `1.5` then under 1.5 displaying `2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/reduce.html) to get the total value of ratings, then divide it by the number of ratings. See the concrete example on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=6ee4335583af699aa8dd35bf020e935a&null_safety=true).